# Get Social websites profile link and attach those to a django user

Tags: django, facebook, twitter, oauth, python-social-auth

I am working on a django app. What i want to do is that in my app i want to allow people to add their facebook, twitter and google+ profile links but after only getting authenticated to these. I want my website should recognize a user if it gets login from facebook or twitter or g+ and redirects it to the user page with which these social media profile links are attached. I am trying it to do using python requests package. But i am not getting a way how can i do it. Should i get a oauth token from the site to store or should store the profile link of the user. I have implemented the social authentication mecanism using **python-social-auth**

Please suggest me.

A small example will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you want to [extend the pipeline](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html) with a function to redirect users.  You can use [Social User](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storage.html#social-user) to get at the auth used to log in.

Comment: Exactly I am looking for the same. Thank you. Now i am trying to implement this by giving links on my template